# Call multiple parent methods from child modal ngx boostrap angular 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm able to call a parent method from a child method however when I try to call another method It doesn't call the second method from the parent component.

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ActaModalComponent,{data, class: 'modal-lg'});
        this.bsModalRef.content.saved.take(1).subscribe(this.listActs.bind(this));
        this.bsModalRef.content.update.take(1).subscribe(this.listBits.bind(this));
```

I call the first method from the child model like this

```
saved: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
update: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

this.saved.emit();
this.update.emit();
```

I've been searching for anything similar on the web with no luck, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing the @Output decorator? Does this help?

```
@Output() saved = new EventEmitter<any>()
@Output() update = new EventEmitter<any>()
```

Also is `take(1)` necessary? That will cause the stream to complete after the first emit I believe.

Comment: thanks for answering, I removed take(1) and add the decorator @Output() and Still the same behavior. calls only the first method.

Comment: what docs are you following? can you provide a link? you using ngx-bootstrap? what version? with bootstrap 3 or 4? can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz that you can share? is this.update.emit() definitely being called? thx

Comment: I'm using ngx-boostrap 3.0.1 docs here https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals, ill create a stackblitz.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem in stackblitz I got an error loading modals there :(